# Can't Create Database Diagrams

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

In SQL 2008, Is it a way to grant permission to developer for view and create database diagrams without giving them dbo permission?

Answer (score 16):

To take credentials to create db. Diagram, Try this query:

```
EXEC dbo.sp_changedbowner @loginame = N'sa', @map = false
```

Answer (score 11):

You need to change database owner to be able to create database diagrams.

To change the database owner:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::AshrafTestDB TO sa
```

Then refresh databases in object explorer in SSMS.

Now you should be able to add new diagrams.

Answer (score 2):

From Books Online:

> To use Database Diagram Designer, it
>   must first be set up by a member of
>   the db_owner role to control access to
>   diagrams.

And

> any user with access to a database can
>   create a diagram

In other words, a user with db_owner permissions must first enable diagrams in the database (to create the sysdiagrams table) and then anyone can create them. See Books Online for more information.

Comment: I've permission to access the database but can't create diagram

Answer (score 2):

I had permissions, yet i couldn't create diagram. After doing this, it worked

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME; -- get your server name

ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[*databasename*] TO [*servername*\Administrator];
```

Comment: This is what worked for me, and it was simple.

Answer (score 1):

EXEC sp_changedbowner 'sa';
--as simple as this :-)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks! As simple as that ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can find a good description here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43946/permission-required-to-view-a-database-diagram

and here: 
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1816/getting-started-with-sql-server-database-diagrams/

These have helped me to solve my issue.